# what's the difference between almost equal and exactly equal for two random variables?

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence

Problem: two random variables $X$ and $Y$ are almost surely equal, can we say that $X=Y$? if not, can anyone name a counter example?

Comment: Suppose that $Y$ is a uniform variable on $[0,1]$ and that $X=Y$ if $Y\notin \mathbb Q$ and $X=0$ if $Y\in \mathbb Q$.  Or, to keep it simple, just suppose that $X=0$ if $Y=.5$.

Comment: There's this thing with probability where continuous variables have $P(X=x)=0$, so despite these exceptions, the variables are surely equal.

Comment: In short, "random variables are almost surely equal" if they are equal for all outcomes with the *exception* of some that occur with probability measure zero.